# Simple JS Event Calendar - Need Current Day Highlighted and an Event Info Popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, calendar

Trying to make a monthly calendar that displays scheduled events in gray and gives a popup with more information about the event on *mousehover*.

Additionally, I wanted to highlight the current day of the month in pink. My code was working a couple days ago but it doesn't seem to work anymore and I can't seem to figure out the problem.

HTML:

```
<!--ignore all this -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Kendall Lee Kasper | Events</title> 
</head>
  <nav>
    <!--Logo Within Navigation Bar-->
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/HYzJLrm.png" class="logo">
    <!--Mobile Navigation Setup -->
    <button id="nav-open">&#9776;</button>
    <span class="deskNav">
    <a href="http://omega.uta.edu/~slc1101/courses/ctec4350/semester-project/index.php">HOME</a> 
    <a href="http://omega.uta.edu/~slc1101/courses/ctec4350/semester-project/about.php">ABOUT</a> 
    <a href="#">EVENTS</a> 
    <a href="http://omega.uta.edu/~slc1101/courses/ctec4350/semester-project/gallery.php">GALLERY</a> 
    <a href="http://omega.uta.edu/~slc1101/courses/ctec4350/semester-project/booking.php">BOOKING</a> 
    </span>
      <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <button id="nav-close"> X </button>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://omega.uta.edu/~slc1101/courses/ctec4350/semester-project/about.php">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://omega.uta.edu/~slc1101/courses/ctec4350/semester-project/gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://omega.uta.edu/~slc1101/courses/ctec4350/semester-project/booking.php">Booking</a></li>
    </ul>   
    </div>
    </nav>
<body>
<div class="section group">
  <div class="col span_2_of_2">
      <span class="textstyling">
         <center>
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Y1uU2NM.png" class="border">
        <hr>
           <img src="http://i.imgur.com/w0tJXYE.png" class="mobileImg">
           <p>
        </center>
<!--CALENDAR CODE STARTS HERE-->
    <div class="month"> 
  <ul>
    <li class="prev">&#10094;</li>
    <li class="next">&#10095;</li>
    <li>
      <center>November<br>
      <span style="font-size:18px">2016</span>
      </center>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
 <!-- POPUP DIV TO DISPLAY EVENT INFO-->
    <div id="pop-up">
     Event info
    </div>
<ul class="days"> 
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li class="scheduled">5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li class="scheduled">15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li class="scheduled">18</li>
  <li class="scheduled">19</li>
  <li>20</li>
  <li>21</li>
  <li class="scheduled">22</li>
  <li>23</li>
  <li>24</li>
  <li>25</li>
  <li>26</li>
  <li>27</li>
  <li>28</li>
  <li>29</li>
  <li>30</li>
</ul>
</div>
<!--CALENDAR HTML ENDS HERE-->
    <hr>
        <center>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/n9x7PV5.png" class="border">
  </center>
    </span>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
/* Month header */
.month {
    padding: 70px 12px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #FA89C4;
}

/* Month list */
.month ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.month ul li {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

/* Previous button inside month header */
.month .prev {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

/* Next button */
.month .next {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

/* Weekdays (Mon-Sun) */
.weekdays {
    padding: 5px 12px;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color:#ddd;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.weekdays li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 13.6%;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Days (1-31) */
.days {
    padding: 5px 12px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #eee;
    border-top: 5px solid #ddd;
    margin: 0;
}

.days li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#777;
}

/* Highlight the "current" day */
.days li .active {
    padding: 5px;
    background: #FF47A6;
    color: white !important
}

.days li .scheduled {
    padding: 5px;
    background: #C2C2C2;
    color: white !important
}

.days li .event {
    cursor: default;
}

    .scheduled {
      background: #C2C2C2;
    }

    div#pop-up {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 280px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
  font-size: 90%;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var novEvents = {
  5: "Pride Week Drag Show @ UT Arlington | 7:00pm",
  15: "Twisted Tuesday @ Rainbow Lounge | 11:00pm",
  18: "All Star Drag Show @ Club 1851 | 10:30pm",
  19: "All Star Drag Show @ Club 1851 | 10:30pm",
  22: "Twisted Tuesday @ Rainbow Lounge | 11:00pm"
};

$(".scheduled").hover(function(){
   $('div#pop-up').show();
      $('div#pop-up').show();
  }, function() {
    $('div#pop-up').hide();
});


// wrap the Events scripts in its own scope
(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        setActiveDate();
        setEventDates();
    });

    function setActiveDate() {
        var currentMonthDate = new Date().getDate();
        $('.days li').each(function (i, ele) {
            if ($(ele).text() == currentMonthDate) {
                $(ele).html($('<div>', { class: 'active event', html: $(ele).html(), title: ''}));
            }
        });
    }

    function setEventDates() {
        $.get('getEvents.php', null, function (data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            $('.days li').each(function (i, ele) {
                var currentDate = "11/" + $(ele).text() + "/2016";
                if (!$(ele).hasClass('scheduled') && $.inArray(currentDate, data) != -1) {
                    $(ele).html($('<div>', { class: 'scheduled event', html: $(ele).html(), title: 'Info' }));
                }
            });

            setDateMouseEvents();            
        })
    }

    function setDateMouseEvents(){
        $('.event').click(function(){
            $('<div>', {title: 'Event'}).dialog();
        }).tooltip();
    }
})(jQuery)
```

I know the code is janky; it's my first try at making a calendar and I'm on a tight deadline.

Here's a pastebin with all the code that might be easier to read: http://pastebin.com/mPg1pEWn

And here's what the final result looks like right now:
http://omega.uta.edu/~slc1101/courses/ctec4350/semester-project/events.php

The scheduled events are highlighted, but the problem is I'm having trouble highlighting the current day and getting the div#pop-up to display event information.

If anyone has any solutions or suggestions on how to improve my code, please let me know!

Comment: If you are on a 'tight deadline' perhaps you could consider using a plugin and not reinventing the wheel? Take a look a [fullcalendar.io](https://fullcalendar.io/)!

Comment: You may get a better answer for your question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Also you should paste any errors you get - 'not working' is not very helpful.

Comment: (For _Code Review_, be sure to present code presumed working, only; see [What topics can I ask about on Code Review?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).)